# Need to filter particular process result from the PS command

Tags: powershell

```
get-nettcpconnection | select local*,remote*,state,@{Name='Process';Expression={(Get-Process -Id $_.OwningProcess).ProcessName }}
```

is listing the all process, I need to filter by process name.

Comment: 1) why the `virtual-box` tag? Why not `Linux` or such? 2) " I need to filter by process name" - why note pipe it to grep? `<existing stuff> | grep <process name to find>`?

Comment: Running the Power shell command in Windows server 2012

Comment: Ah, I see. I didn't recognize it, as I would personally have code some quick Python. Try removing the virtual-box tag & adding a windows PowerShell tag. Doe sit have a `grep` commend? If not, maybe try Cygwin or the Windows `bash` shell? Good luck :-)

Answer (score 0):

if I understood the question correctly, you want to have only certain processes returned. you can do that with a `where` filter.

add the processes you want to have returned in `$searchfor`

```
$searchfor = @("wininit","TeamViewer")
get-nettcpconnection | 
    select local*,remote*,state,@{Name='Process';Expression={(Get-Process -Id $_.OwningProcess).ProcessName }} |
        where { $_.Process -in $searchfor }
```

you could also do it like this, which is probably a bit faster, since you run `get-nettcpconnection` only for the processes you're interested in:

```
$searchfor = @("wininit","TeamViewer")
Get-Process $searchfor | % { 
    $Proc = $_
    Get-nettcpconnection -OwningProcess $_.ID |
        select local*,remote*,state,@{Name='Process';Expression={$Proc.ProcessName}}
}
```